# Passing cookies in request spec

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm trying to pass a cookie when doing a GET request, using rspec 2 and rails 3.

I've tried the following so far.

```
get "/", {}, {"Cookie" => "uuid=10"} # cookies[:uuid] is nil
request.cookies[:uuid] = 10 # request is nil
@request.env["Cookie"] = "uuid=10" # @request is nil
helper.request.cookies[:uuid] # helper is not defined
cookies[:uuid] = 10 # cookies[:uuid] is nil
controller.cookies[:uuid] = 10 # cookies is nil
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9):

What works for me in RSpec Request tests is passing the HTTP Cookie header explicitly:

```
  before do
    get "/api/books", headers: { Cookie: "auth=secret" }
  end
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by a more concrete example

Answer (score 8):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23601146/175981), you can use the `cookies` method within request specs:

```
before { cookies['foo'] = 'bar' }
```

I tried @phoet's solution involving `ActionDispatch::Request.any_instance.stubs`, but it throws an error along with a seemingly unrelated deprecation message in RSpec 3.4.

Answer (score 5):

I was a little confused by how you did this at first, but it's actually really easy. Inside of Rails's ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest (or in rspec's case a `:request` spec) you have access to a cookies variable.

It works like this:

```
# set up your cookie
cookies["fruits"] = ["apple", "pear"]

# hit your endpoint
get fruits_path, {}, {}

# this works!
expect(cookies["fruits"]).to eq(["apple", "pear"])
```

Answer (score 4):

i had a similar issue and i did not find a proper solution to this.

the [rspec-rails docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/cookies) state that it should be possible:

```
# spec
request.cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
get :some_action
response.cookies['foo'].should eq('modified bar')
```

in my spec `request` is always `nil` before executing a get.

i am now mocking the cookies:

```
before { ActionDispatch::Request.any_instance.stubs(cookies: {locale: :en}) }
```

[this guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rspec/dHZCApH5MGA) has a similar problem.

Comment: The docs you link to are for controller specs, not request specs, which is why `request` returns `nil`. Also trying to figure out how to do this in RSpec 3.4.

Answer (score 4):

In `spec/requests/some_spec.rb` you can use `Rack::Test::Methods` to set and read cookies.

```
describe 'Something' do

  include Rack::Test::Methods

  it 'can set cookies' do
    set_cookie "foo=red"
    post '/some/endpoint', params, headers
    expect(last_request.cookies[:foo]).to eq('red')
  end

end
```

Documentation:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/MockSession#set_cookie-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

I got your case. In my case, I need the `_sid` from cookies in the controller `request.cookies['_sid']`

I fixed by

```rb
before do
  @request.cookies['_sid'] = sid
  get :show, id: job_id
end
```

it works for me.

so in your case, you can have a try.

```rb
before do
  @request.cookies[:uuid]
  get "/", {}
end
```