# Rails/rspec: how to set cookies in a request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How do I set cookies in my request specs?

The solutions on the following page did not work:

[Rspec: setting cookies in a helper test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475989/rspec-setting-cookies-in-a-helper-test)

Namely, `request.cookies[:whatever] = 'something'` says that `request` is a `nil` object. I also tried `helper.cookies[:whatever] = 'something'`, and that also did not work (`helper` in that case was `nil`).

Comment: Can you share your spec?

Answer (score 5):

Try just the following:

```
cookies[:whatever] = 'something'
```

Comment: This does NOT appear to work for request specs, only controller specs.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you are using the rspec-rails gem and are requiring 'rspec/rails' in your spec_helper, not just 'rspec'.

Comment: I am using that gem and am requiring that file, still no luck